# I have permissions and still get the java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-permissions

I'am targeting SdkVersion 29 and I'm trying to play a song located in my external storage sdCard but it keep showing this error :

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/E0FD-1813/Music/3_INTRO.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

V/MediaPlayerNative: isPlaying: no active player
I/chatty: uid=10325(com.android.leafter) Thread-6 identical 32 lines
V/MediaPlayerNative: isPlaying: no active player
V/MediaPlayerNative: isPlaying: no active player
I/chatty: uid=10325(com.android.leafter) Thread-6 identical 26 lines
```

i have a fragment called musicfragment that contains a listview that will hold the songs when the getSongs method is triggered but i know that i sould have permession so I added the read external storage

manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.leafter">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

here i implemented the runtime permission :

```
public class MusicFragment extends Fragment {

//    ------------------------------- Permission ----------------------------------------------------
    private ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
                if (isGranted) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"permission is granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    getSongs();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"permission not granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
//    ------------------------------- END Permission ----------------------------------------------------
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 99;
    public MusicFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View musicFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_music, container, false);

        listSongs = new ArrayList<>();
        songAdapter = new SongAdapter(getContext(), listSongs);

        lvSongs = (ListView) musicFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.lvSongs);
        lvSongs.setAdapter(songAdapter);
//----------------------------------------------------- PERMISSION SECTION ---------------------------

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Already granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getSongs();
        } else {
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"request sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        lvSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Song currentSong = listSongs.get(position);

                Intent musicPlayerIntent = new Intent(getContext(), MusicPlayer_Activity.class);
                musicPlayerIntent.putExtra("currentSong", currentSong);
                startActivity(musicPlayerIntent);
            }
        });

        return musicFragmentView;
    }
//----------------------------------------------------- PERMISSION SECTION ----------------------------
    private void getSongs() {
        // get songs from external storage
    }
}
```

then in the musicPlayer activity i retrieve the current song from the intent

```
public class MusicPlayer_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

//    Views delcaration

    TextView tvTime, tvDuration, songTitle, songArtist;
    Button btnPlay;
    SeekBar seekBarTime, seekBarVolume;

    MediaPlayer musicPlayer;
    AudioManager audiomanager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_player_);
      // Views declaration ...
      
        Song currentSong = (Song) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("currentSong");

        songTitle.setText(currentSong.getTitle());
        songArtist.setText(currentSong.getArtist());

        musicPlayer = new MediaPlayer();        
        try {
            musicPlayer.setDataSource("file://"+currentSong.getPath());
            Toast.makeText(this,"after setDataSource file://"+currentSong.getPath(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            musicPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btnPlay) {
            if (musicPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                musicPlayer.pause();
                btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
            } else {
                musicPlayer.start();
                btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when i run the app on the songs don't get played and i get the error shown above

**PS :  i tried to put a .mp3 song as a resource in the raw folder and use MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.song) and it works**

Comment: If you are tergeting Api29, you probably want this : `requestLegacyExternalStorage=true` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` within your manifest `<applicaion>`as a section attribute.  Note : this is a temporary stay of executon, as of August 2021 all new/updated apps on Google Play need to target Api30 - which this flag ceases to have any meaning to Api30.  If this is simply a toy project then don't worry and just add the attiribute flag.

Answer (score 0):

The File Not Found could be related to two issues:

- You do not have the correct permissions
- The folder or file doesn't exist
  If you review the error in your Logcat, you can usually determine the specific details. Also, using a File app on your device, you should be able to see if file with that name actually does in that folder.

What level SDK are you targeting? If you have targetSdkVersion 30 in your app's build.gradle file, you need to update your code to adhere to a recent policy change that Google made.

While Google's documentation isn't great, this was the best information I've been able to find to learn more about this:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955 (make sure to expand the sections at the bottom of this page)

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/mwaqn1/scoped_storage_recap/ (this one focuses more on Scoped Storage, but is still helpful)

If you aren't sure if the directory exists, you can use code such as this to create it:

```
final File root = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)));

// Create the directory if it doesn't exist
if (!root.exists()) {
    boolean wasSuccessful = root.mkdirs();

    // Display Toast message if the directory creation wasn't successful
    if (!wasSuccessful) {
        mToast = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.photo_directory_not_created_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        mToast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have targetSdkVersion = 29
i already checked the path of the song in my phone and in logcat and they match but still getting permessio denied and filenotfound could you please explain to me a bit more what i should change or check since am new to android this is my first project

Comment: what is scoped storage ?

Comment: You picked a challenging project for your first one! Here is a good Android developer training site to start with to learn more about how to manage storage, permissions, and accessing files that were either created by your app or others: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: it's an academic project soo no choice i must do it :p
if you have any remark or maybe a fix i'm interested

Comment: i tried to lower the targetSDKversion from 29 to 27 and it works

Comment: Great, by lowering the targetSdk you know that it was a security permissions issue based on how you were accessing the file. If this answer helped you, please mark it as correct.